# Where does tlmgr store the packages?

Tags: texlive, tex-core, tlmgr

As given on https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html , tlmgr can be used to install packages. Where does it store these packages? Because then I can copy them to another machine for installation rather than downloading them every time. Thanks for your help.

Edit: I am using Debian Stable Linux.

Comment: In `texmf-dist/tex/latex/` you'll find the latex packages.

Comment: The `tlmgr` packages are stored in the repository as `xz`-compressed tarballs. After they are downloaded, they're expanded and then removed from the local machine. As far as I can see, there is no option for keeping them, but it's rather easy to set up an `rsync` mirror.

Comment: Copies of updated packages are kept as backups by `tlmgr`, though that's obviously not what you want. If you have 2 machines with the architecture, you can simply copy the entire installation from one to the other.

Comment: Once you're installed on one machine, `tlmgr backup --all` will make a backup copy of all packages installed on that machine. These are stored in the form of the `.xz` compressed archives @egreg mentioned. However, these must be created from the installed versions. I assume you could then install them on a second machine, but I'd also assume they may not be identical to those you download initially. However, I'm not sure about this. @egreg might know, though.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using Linux. Is there a particular folder where the xz compressed tarballs are stored in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am trying to answer this very unclear question:

- if you are asking where `tlmgr` installs the packages to, then it is the path relative to the location of `tlmgr` two levels up. So if the `tlmgr` binary is in `/a/b/c/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`, then it will install packages into `/a/b/c`.
- if you are asking where `tlmgr` saves downloaded packages (like `latex.tar.xz` etc), then this is a temporary directory that will disappear after installation. Packages are not kept for reuse.
- if you are asking where `tlmgr` saves backups of packages *before* doing updates, then this is again relative to the location of the `tlmgr` binary, two levels up and then `tlpkg/backup`, but this can be configured with `tlmgr`.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for a very clear answer. I had meant option 2 (where tlmgr saves downloaded packages).